# javascript anonymous function : why my script doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to try to a lib ala jquery but I don't understand why my method getUrl doesn't output anything, do you ?

mylib.js

```
    (function () {

    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var index = scripts.length - 1;
    var thisScript = scripts[index];

    var myLib = {       
        getUrl: function() {
            return thisScript;
        }               
    }
}

if (!window.$$) {window.$$ = myLib}

)();
```

and in mytest.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="mylib.js" type=text/javascript></script>
</head>

<body>
    <DIV id=url>url</DIV>   
    <script>
    var url = $$.getUrl();
    jQuery("#url").html(url);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code had a misplaced `}`.

```
(function() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var index = scripts.length - 1;
    var thisScript = scripts[index];

    var myLib = {       
        getUrl: function() {
            return thisScript;
        }               
    };
//} <-- Remove this. 

  if (!window.$$) {window.$$ = myLib;}
} // <-- Add this, the closing brace of the anonymous function
)();
```